# Android - How do I "start" or "initialize" a Fragment from an activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a class called `DummyFragment` that extends `Fragment`.

```
public class DummyFragment extends Fragment {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setRetainInstance(true);

        Log.i("myapp","test");
    }
}
```

Now, in my parent activity, I want to "run" this fragment.

This is my `FirstActivity.java`:

```
public class FirstActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

        // How do I run/start my fragment? I want it's onCreate method to fire
        Fragment fraggy = new DummyFragment();
    }
}
```

How do I run/start my fragment? I want my `DummyFragment`'s `onCreate` method to fire.

Comment: Start [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's plenty of documentation! Everything you need is already [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager()
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

Fragment fraggy = new DummyFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fraggy);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Of course, you'll need the container in you activity layout.